# Gutenberg Custom Block Not Validating - Ideas?

Tags: block-editor

I added a Custom Block in Gutenberg (which basically customizes the Gutenberg `Section` block type that is made available by [Ultimate Addons for Gutenberg](https://ultimategutenberg.com/)), in Wordpress 5.7.  It is a block I call let's call `exercise`.  In admin I can add the block fine, and on front end it seems to display fine, but **in admin I get this block validation error**:

```
blocks.min.js?ver=7ed7fe32dad771c4e0af4f56539ff156:2 Block validation: Block validation failed for `uagb/section` ({name: 'uagb/section', icon: {…}, keywords: Array(3), providesContext: {…}, usesContext: Array(0), …}).

Content generated by `save` function:

<div id="an-exercise" class="contenttype-wrapper sometopictype-exercise" content-id="" data-id="5830199b"><div class="heading d-flex flex-row"><i class="contenticon fas fa-guitar fa-7x"></i><div class="col"><div class="row"><span class="content-name">Exercise</span></div><div class="row"><h3 class="topictype-title">an exercise</h3></div></div></div><section class="wp-block-uagb-section uagb-section__wrap uagb-section__background-undefined" id="uagb-section-5830199b"><div class="uagb-section__overlay"></div><div class="uagb-section__inner-wrap"></div></section></div>

Content retrieved from post body:

<div id="an-exercise" class="contenttype-wrapper sometopictype-exercise" content-id="" data-id="5830199b"><div class="heading d-flex flex-row"><i class="contenticon fas fa-guitar fa-7x"></i><div class="col"><div class="row"><span class="content-name">Exercise</span></div><div class="row"><h3 class="topictype-title">an exercise</h3></div></div></div><section class="wp-block-uagb-section uagb-section__wrap uagb-section__background-undefined uagb-block-5830199b"><div class="uagb-section__overlay"></div><div class="uagb-section__inner-wrap"></div></section></div>
```

**Now, I can see the essence of the error**, since the code generated by save function contains `id="uagb-section-5830199b` whereas retrieved from body there is `uagb-block-5830199b`.

**I just can't figure out why there would be this discrepancy**.

So I thought I would share my code here and see if anyone sees anything obviously wrong.

First, here is the block code in javascript which is included in my plugin that I use to create the block:

```
const { assign } = lodash;
const { addFilter } = wp.hooks;
const { __ } = wp.i18n;

// Enable spacing control on the following blocks
const enableBlockContentTypeAttribute = [
    'uagb/section',
];

// Available spacing control options
const contenttypeControlOptions = [
    {
        label: __( 'None' ),
        value: '',
    },
    {
        label: __( 'Exercise' ),
        value: 'exercise',
    },
    {
        label: __( 'Concept' ),
        value: 'concept',
    },
    {
        label: __( 'Something' ),
        value: 'something',
    },
];

/**
 * Add spacing control attribute to block.
 *
 * @param {object} settings Current block settings.
 * @param {string} name Name of block.
 *
 * @returns {object} Modified block settings.
 */
const addBlockContentTypeAttribute = ( settings, name ) => {
    // Do nothing if it's another block than our defined ones.

    if ( ! enableBlockContentTypeAttribute.includes( name ) ) {
        return settings;
    }
    //console.log('Add content type option');
    // Use Lodash's assign to gracefully handle if attributes are undefined
    settings.attributes = assign( settings.attributes, {
        contenttype: {
            type: 'string',
            default: contenttypeControlOptions[ 0 ].value,
        },
        contenttitle: {
            type: 'string',
            default: '',
        },
        contentname: {
            type: 'string',
            default: contenttypeControlOptions[ 0 ].label,
        },
        contentid: {
            type: 'string',
            default: '',
        },

    } );

    return settings;
};

addFilter( 'blocks.registerBlockType', 'my-mods/attribute/contenttype', addBlockContentTypeAttribute );

const { createHigherOrderComponent } = wp.compose;
const { Fragment } = wp.element;
const { InspectorControls, InnerBlocks } = wp.blockEditor;
const { PanelBody, PanelRow, SelectControl, TextControl } = wp.components;

/**
 * Create HOC to add content type control to inspector controls of block.
 */
const withContentTypeControl = createHigherOrderComponent( ( BlockEdit ) => {
    return ( props ) => {
    // Do nothing if it's another block than our defined ones.
    if ( ! enableBlockContentTypeAttribute.includes( props.name ) ) {
        return (
            <BlockEdit { ...props } />
    );
    }
    //console.log(props.attributes);
    const { contenttype } = props.attributes;
    const { contenttitle } = props.attributes;
    const { contentname } = props.attributes;

    function getContentTitle ( content ) {
        props.setAttributes({contenttitle: content});
    }

    return (
        <Fragment>
        <BlockEdit { ...props } />
<InspectorControls>
    <PanelBody
    title={ __( 'Choose Content Type' ) }
    initialOpen={ true }
        >
        <SelectControl
    label={ __( 'Content Type' ) }
    value={ contenttype }
    options={ contenttypeControlOptions }
    onChange={ ( selectedContentTypeOption ) => {
        var name = contenttypeControlOptions.filter(obj => {
                return obj.value === selectedContentTypeOption
            });
        //console.log(name);
        name = name[0].label;
        //console.log(name);
        props.setAttributes( {
            contenttype: selectedContentTypeOption,
            contentname: name,
        } );
    } }
/>

<TextControl
    label={ __( 'Content Title' ) }
    value={ contenttitle }
    onChange={ ( getContentTitle ) => {
        props.setAttributes( {
            contenttitle: getContentTitle,
        });
    }}
/>

</PanelBody>
    </InspectorControls>
    </Fragment>
);
};
}, 'withSpacingControl' );

addFilter( 'editor.BlockEdit', 'my-mods/with-contenttype-control', withContentTypeControl );



// do something with these attributes - add header to section if exercise type block
const addContentTypeMarkup = ( element, blockType, attributes ) => {
    // Do nothing if it's another block than our defined ones.
    if ( ! enableBlockContentTypeAttribute.includes( blockType.name ) ) {
        return element;
    }
    if ( attributes.contenttitle) {

        // add header with anchor link and class name
        var title_slug = attributes.contenttitle.trim().split(/\s+/).join('-');

        var iconclassbase='contenticon ';
        var iconclass='';
        switch(attributes.contenttype) {
            case 'exercise':
                iconclass =  'fas fa-guitar';
                break;
            case 'concept':
                iconclass = 'fas fa-atom';
                break;
            default:
                iconclass = 'fas fa-atom';
        }
        iconclass = iconclassbase + iconclass;

        return (
            <React.Fragment>
            <div id = {`${title_slug}`} className = {`contenttype-wrapper sometopictype-${attributes.contenttype}`} content-id="" data-id = {`${attributes.block_id}`}>
                <div className = "heading d-flex flex-row">
                    <i className={`${iconclass} fa-7x`}></i>
                    <div className = "col">
                       <div className = "row"><span className="content-name">{attributes.contentname}</span></div>
                       <div className = "row"><h3 className="topictype-title" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={ { __html: attributes.contenttitle } }></h3></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                {element}
            </div>
        </React.Fragment>
    )
    } else {
        return element;
    }
    //return saveElementProps;
};

addFilter( 'blocks.getSaveElement', 'my-mods/add-content-type-markup', addContentTypeMarkup);
```

And here is the php code for the plugin that I made to create my custom block:

```
/ this is to alter uagb-section block
function my_block_mods_backend_enqueue() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'my-block-mods', // Unique handle.
        plugins_url( 'blocks/js/dest/block.bundle.js', __FILE__ ), // block.js: We register the block here.
        array( 'wp-blocks', 'wp-i18n', 'wp-element', 'wp-hooks', 'lodash', 'wp-editor' ) // Dependencies, defined above.
    );
}
add_action( 'enqueue_block_editor_assets', 'my_block_mods_backend_enqueue' );
```

Maybe it has to do with the fact that I originally worked on this a couple years ago with Wordpress 5.1, and now using 5.7, and perhaps there are some nuanced changes?

Also, for what it is worth, I found the code in the Ultimate Gutenberg Addons plugin that is responsible for creating the `section` markup. namely,

```
function (e, t, n) {
    "use strict";
    var a = n(0), l = n.n(a), r = n(1), i = n(364), o = (n.n(i), n(365)), c = (n.n(o), n(366)), s = n(367), u = (n(118), wp.i18n.__), p = wp.blocks.registerBlockType, m = wp.editor.InnerBlocks;
    p("uagb/section", {
        title: uagb_blocks_info.blocks["uagb/section"].title,
        description: uagb_blocks_info.blocks["uagb/section"].description,
        icon: r.a.section,
        category: uagb_blocks_info.category,
        keywords: [u("section"), u("wrapper"), u("uag")],
        attributes: c.a,
        edit: s.a,
        getEditWrapperProps: function (e) {
            var t = e.align, n = e.contentWidth;
            if (("left" === t || "right" === t || "wide" === t || "full" === t) && "full_width" == n)return {"data-align": t}
        },
        save: function (e) {
            var t = (e.attributes, e.className), n = e.attributes, a = n.block_id, r = n.tag, i = n.backgroundType, o = n.backgroundVideo, c = n.contentWidth, s = n.align, u = "";
            "full_width" == c && ("wide" != s && "full" != s || (u = "align" + s));
            var p = "" + r;
            return wp.element.createElement(p, {
                className: l()(t, "uagb-section__wrap", "uagb-section__background-" + i, u),
                id: "uagb-section-" + a
            }, wp.element.createElement("div", {className: "uagb-section__overlay"}), "video" == i && wp.element.createElement("div", {className: "uagb-section__video-wrap"}, o && wp.element.createElement("video", {
                        autoplay: !0,
                        loop: !0,
                        muted: !0,
                        playsinline: !0
                    }, wp.element.createElement("source", {
                        src: o.url,
                        type: "video/mp4"
                    }))), wp.element.createElement("div", {className: "uagb-section__inner-wrap"}, wp.element.createElement(m.Content, null)))
        },
        deprecated: [{
            attributes: c.a, save: function (e) {
                var t = (e.attributes, e.className), n = e.attributes, a = n.block_id, r = n.tag, i = n.backgroundType, o = n.backgroundVideo, c = n.contentWidth, s = n.align, u = "";
                "full_width" == c && ("wide" != s && "full" != s || (u = "align" + s));
                var p = "" + r;
                return wp.element.createElement(p, {
                    className: l()(t, "uagb-section__wrap", "uagb-section__background-" + i, u),
                    id: "uagb-section-" + a
                }, wp.element.createElement("div", {className: "uagb-section__overlay"}), "video" == i && wp.element.createElement("div", {className: "uagb-section__video-wrap"}, o && wp.element.createElement("video", {
                            src: o.url,
                            autoPlay: !0,
                            loop: !0,
                            muted: !0
                        })), wp.element.createElement("div", {className: "uagb-section__inner-wrap"}, wp.element.createElement(m.Content, null)))
            }
        }]
    })
```

So it is a matter of figuring out why that markup is being altered and where/why?

Thanks!

Comment: It looks like the original block that you are wrapping has changed. This might not be your issue at all. Does your code work if you create a completely fresh page with a fresh usage of the block?

Comment: Just tried, and same problem.

Comment: What if you disable your code entirely and try the original block?

Comment: It works if I disable my plugin and add a Gutenberg `Section` block. Interesting result - I just don't see where my code would be causing the validation error.

Comment: Hm, neither can I. When you inspect the HTML on the front end, which version of the markup do you see? And what about when viewing the HTML in the editor? Can you tell when/if it's being changed?

Comment: On front end the block looks fine and has this markup for the `uagb/section` block:```<section class="wp-block-uagb-section uagb-section__wrap uagb-section__background-undefined uagb-block-5830199b"><div class="uagb-section__overlay"></div><div class="uagb-section__inner-wrap">``` Since the section block works without errors when I disable my plugin, and since UAGB is adding the `id='uagb-section-5830199b`, I suppose that means down the line somewhere the block save function is stripping off that id and replacing by adding `uagb-block-5830199b` to the class. So problem with my save function?

Comment: I tried extending core/group and same problem, so it has something to do with my code. I guess in newer versions of wordpress (I am using 5.7, earlier when I had this working it was 5.2) there is an id tag added to the block. With core/group it adds "id=ex", if for example, my `contentname` property is "ex". No idea how wordpress is choosing one of my custom attributes to assign to an id property, but that is what it is doing. So I think maybe I am using properties and/or attributes incorrectly, or using properties when I should be using attributes or vice versa. Any idea on how to proceed?

Comment: @Brian "I originally worked on this a couple years ago with Wordpress 5.1, and now using 5.7" - did you just update from WordPress 5.1 to 5.7, which means you never updated to v5.2, v5.3, etc.? Because looking at the plugin codebase, the `id` attribute has long been deprecated (see "Now blocks use class to generate dynamic CSS instead of ID" [here - v1.14.4 release](https://github.com/brainstormforce/ultimate-addons-for-gutenberg/releases/tag/v1.14.4)), so you should've noticed the validation error since long ago..?

Comment: And there's an easy way to prevent the error for **new** blocks of the `uagb/section` block type, however, you would need to re-save your posts which already have that block. And actually, why didn't you update to WordPress 5.8.1? :) Also, which version of the plugin you're using?

Comment: Hi, I was using plugin 1.13.6. Then took a break from web development. Then started setting up new site, right from Wordpress 5.7 and using latest UAGB plugin (prior I was using 1.13.6). I now have things squared away using core/group instead. Thanks for the insights!